# batch file command to copy file

Tags: batch-file

```
if EXIST C:\Users\g511411\Desktop\unsigned\*.tar (for /R C:\Users\g511411\Desktop\unsigned\GNU_ARM_DEBUG %%f in (*.bin) do copy "%%f" C:\Users\g511411\Desktop\dll\Destination 
for /R C:\Users\g511411\Desktop\unsigned\GNU_ARM_DEBUG %%f in (*.txt) do copy "%%f" C:\Users\g511411\Desktop\dll\Prm)
```

I have an `unsigned` folder which has `.tar` file and `GNU_ARM_DEBUG` folder. According to second command in `if`: if `.tar` is present in `unsigned` folder then copy `.txt` from `GNU_ARM_DEBUG` folder to `Prm` folder. But `GNU_ARM_DEBUG` also has `Resources` folder and this command also copies `.txt` file from `Resources` folder which I don't want. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace your second line with

```
 xcopy "C:\Users\g511411\Desktop\unsigned\GNU_ARM_DEBUG\*.txt" "C:\Users\g511411\Desktop\dll\Prm\"
)
```

Note that adding `/L` to the `xcopy` command will simply display a `L`ist of the copies batch proposes to do - good for checking that the command is correct.

You could also add `/y` to the `xcopy` to auto-overwrite existing files, and add `>nul` / `2>nul` to the end of the line to suppress reports/error reports.